# linux linking assembly with gcc gives many errors

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to compile and link a simple "hello, world!" program with GCC. This program uses the "printf" C function. The problem that I am having is that the terminal throws back multiple errors. I am running Archlinux, compiling with NASM, linking with GCC. Here is my code:

```
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
; helloworld.asm
; 
; Compile: nasm -f elf32 helloworld.asm
; Link: gcc helloworld.o
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SECTION .data
    message db "Hello, World",0
SECTION .text
    global  main
    extern  printf

    section .text
_main:
    push    message
    call    printf
    add     esp, 4
    ret
```

The errors that I receive are as follows:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.2/libgcc.a     when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone tell me what is causing these errors and what I need to do to fix them?

Thanks in advance,

RileyH

Answer (score 0):

For such things, you should first understand what exactly `gcc` is doing. So use

```
 gcc -v helloworld.o -o helloworld
```

and what is happenning is that you have a 64 bits Linux and linking a 32 bits object in it. So try with

```
 gcc -m32 -v helloworld.o -o helloworld
```

But I think that you should avoid coding assembly today (optimizing compilers do a better work than you can reasonably do). If you absolutely need a few assembly instructions, put some `asm` in your C code.

BTW, you could compile with `gcc -fverbose-asm -O -wall -S helloworld.c` and look inside the generated `helloworld.s`; and you could also pass `.s` files to `gcc`

Comment: It outputs a whole lot of junk (file paths and what not) and then the same error message I originally posted.

Comment: You might need to install the `lib32gcc1` and `gcc-4.7-multilib` packages on your system. Why don't you code x86-64 assembly code (not x86 32 bits assembly) on your 64 bits system?

Comment: How would I do that in terminal? Sorry, but I just newly installed Archlinux for the first time and I don't know much about linux in general.

Comment: Then learn much more about Linux (system administration and command line development) before trying assembler....